# How to write TypeScript SuiteScripts?

Tags: typescript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

If one wanted to write SuiteScript 2.0 using TypeScript, would it need to be transpiled to ES5 to work in Netsuite? Does anyone know what the best options are if SuiteScripts need to be written in TypeScript? Is there an npm module for such a purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a github project that provides SS2.0 types and a few samples. I’ve been using it for a couple of years and it’s been quite nice. Search github for netsuite-types. I cloned the repo some time ago into https://github.com/BKnights/netsuite-types to try to keep it more up-to-date but in grabbing the link I saw I haven’t pushed anything in more than a year. I have added some fixes though and I’ll try to push when I’m back in the office in the new year.

Comment: The original project is at https://github.com/headintheclouddev/typings-suitescript-2.0 and is pretty active (last commit less than 5 hours ago). I would suggest you create a pull request so they can incorporate whatever updates you have made